# Using shift with left click for event without jQuery

Tags: javascript, events, mouseevent, action

My goal is to press a button and perform an action only when the shift key is also pressed. However, it doesn't even seem to recognize the shift key right now. Currently it works with only the right click but like I said, I want it to work with right click + shift.

```
button.addEventListener("oncontextmenu", function(e) {
  document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    console.log("this string won't show");
    if (e.keyCode == 16) {
      console.log("this string won't show either");
    } else {
      console.log(e.keyCode); // again it won't show
    }
  });
  rightShiftClick(e); // this will execute perfectly. 
});
```

Comment: Why are you binding events inside of events? `oncontextmenu` is wrong, should not have the `on`

Comment: I was binding them in hopes of having rightclick + shift work. How is "oncontextmenu" wrong ? It listens to the right click event. I am not sure what is the relevant html code you want to see. its a big file.

Comment: the shift key is in the event object. console.log(e), and events do not have "on", look at keydown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event object tells you if the shift key is pressed and there is no "on" when you are attaching the event.

```
button.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e) { 
    console.log(e.shiftKey); 
});
```

Comment: wow that's all... it seemed so complicated online everywhere. Thank you!